# COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADING Doesn't Work while MULTITHREADING does work out of my C# wrapped class

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, wrapper

I have a C++ class that does whatever work I need it to do and a wrapper for it so I can access it through C#.  The C++ class sets the threading type to APARTMENT THREADING and when I access it from another C++ class, it works fine.  If I run it through my C# wrapper, it only works if the C++ class is set to multithreading.

I tried to set the wrapper to start it's own apartment thread before calling the C++ class but it can't seem to initiallize the thread successfully.  When I print the HRESULT, it says everything completed successfully.

I don't know what I'm missing here and if anyone can help, it would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
-Alex

Comment: Maybe this link can be useful http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/04/07/406341.aspx

Comment: Since there is no code, we can't tell how you are using things. You normally don't _have_ HRESULTS in C# interop, so that makes me wonder how you do things?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say the HRESULTS portion is in the C++ wrapper portion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, doesn't work.  A class cannot set the apartment of a thread reliably unless it *created* the thread.  Which is certainly not the case here, the CLR has created the thread.  And has already called CoInitializeEx(), the selected apartment cannot be changed later.

If your C++ code requires a single-threaded apartment then the C# code has to help.  Either by putting the [STAThread] attribute on the Main() method.  Or by calling Thread.SetApartmentState() when it creates its own Thread to call your code.  A threadpool thread is always MTA, that cannot be changed.

This is an entirely reasonable expectation btw, lots of native code has STA requirements.  Beware that the C# code must also pump a message loop to make the STA work.  This is all taken care of if you create a Winforms or WPF app.